# What is the last argument in validation functions in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Here is a validation function signature in CouchDB:

```
function (newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {}
```

I wonder what the last argument is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki documentation for CouchDB's [Document Update Validation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation) says this is "The security object of the database (introduced in CouchDB-0.11.1)."

This security object describes what admin/reader privileges have been set on the DB, details about its structure and meaning is given in the wiki's [Security Features Overview](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authorization) page.